# ubuntu 64-bit is LP64?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I understnad that there several models for 64-bits: LP64, ILP64 ,LLP64.
I would like to ask which of them is used with ubuntu 64-bit (and the gcc used in this ubuntu) ?

Comment: Hi Pascal, Thanks. What is the command line for giving this information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that Ubuntu 64-bit offers I32LP64 compilation.

You can detect this for yourself with the following code:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void) { 
  printf("%zu %zu %zu\n", 
    CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int),
    CHAR_BIT*sizeof(long),
    CHAR_BIT*sizeof(void*));
}
$ gcc t.c && ./a.out 
32 64 64
```